# React: How to wrap component with HOC? (access login property across components)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

I have a react (with redux & react-router) app that at various points needs to know whether or not a user is logged in based on the state of some data in the store and a bunch of other things tied to data in the store.

To achieve this, I've created a higher order component like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

export function masterComponent(Component){

  class MasterComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
      super(props);
    }

    loggedIn(){
      return this.props.player.token? true : false
    }

    render(){
      return (
        <Component {...this.props} player={{loggedIn: this.loggedIn()}}/>
      );
    }
  }

  UserComponent.propTypes = {
    player: React.PropTypes.object
  };


  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return state;
  }

  return connect(
    mapStateToProps
  )(MasterComponent);

}
```

My question is how is best to wrap this around my individual components? Currently I have implemented it so that each individual component is wrapped when passed to connect which works fine but feels a little inefficient. ie:

```
import {masterComponent} from '../HigherOrderComponents/MasterComponent';

export class ResultsPage extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
.....
  }


  render(){
    return (
       .....
    );
  }
}



export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(masterComponent(ResultsPage));
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on your use case, I see 3 possible solutions. Code below is untested and semi-pseudo.

### Your initial proposal, refactored

```
export function masterComponent(Component) {

  const MasterComponent = (props) => {
    const loggedIn = props.player.token? true : false;

    // initial solution would override player, so you need 
    // something like this
    const player = { 
      ...this.props.player,
      loggedIn,
    };

    return <Component {...this.props} player={player} />
  }

  // Important! Here is the crucial part of the refactoring, 
  // not the coding style changes. Map only the relevant 
  // state properties, otherwise the component would rerender 
  // whenever any state property changed. 
  return connect(state => ({ player: this.state.player }))(MasterComponent);
}
```

### Redux Middleware (my personal choice)

```
function loginMiddleware() {
  return store => next => action => {
    if (action.type === 'ADD_CREDENTIALS') {
      const { player } = store.getState();
      loginService.setPlayer(player);
    }

    // removePlayer if action.type === 'LOGOUT';

    return next(action);
  }
}
```

and in any component you could use

```
loginService.getPlayer()
```

to verify if somebody has logged in or not

**Disadvantage** compared to your approach: If action `'ADD_CREDENTIALS'` has been dispatched, but the component that requests `loginService.getPlayer()` doesn't get rerendered / updated, you might end up with inconsistent state. I'm sure you could solve that with more specific knowledge of your application.

### Context (my least favourite)

Use React [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) and pass the desired property to all other components.