# React Higher Order Component conditional data load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, inheritance, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

Imagine I have some "page" component, which needs to ask for data from a server. The data it requests will depend on whether or not the current user is authenticated. Further, in the event of a login, the page will want to reload the data. My question is, how can I accomplish something like this using HOCs rather than inheritance?

To illustrate the problem, I'll demonstrate a solution using inheritance. The program will have the following objects. I'll leave out the boilerplate code.

- `session`: an `EventEmitter` that emits `start` when the session changes (either a login or a log out).
- `Page`: the superclass that all pages inherit from
- `MyPage`: the subclass of `Page` in this example
- `API`: will be an API class for retrieving data from the server

Here's the code:

```
// Page superclass
class Page extends React.Component {

   componentWillMount() {
      session.on("start", this.loadData);
      this.loadData();
   }

   loadData() {
      // this method is overwritten in subclasses
   }
}

// MyPage subclass
class MyPage extends Page {

   loadData() {
      if(session.isAuthenticated()) {
         API.loadPrivateData();
      } else {
         API.loadPublicData();
      }
   }
}
```

Here's a solution that uses an HOC, but seems less elegant than inheritance. It still requires that every "subclass" page have a method `loadData`, and it requires that method to be called in every "subclass's" `componentWillMount`.

```
// Page HOC
function Page(WrappedComponent) {
   return class EnhancedPage extends React.Component {

      componentWillMount() {
         session.on("start", this.loadData);
         // this._page.loadData() will fail here
         // since this._page is undefined until rendering finishes
      }

      loadData() {
         this._page.loadData();
      }

      render() {
         return <WrappedComponent {...props} ref={(e) => { this._page = e; }} />
      }
   }
}

// MyPage
class MyPage extends React.Component {

   componentWillMount() {
      this.loadData();
   }

   loadData() {
      if(session.isAuthenticated()) {
         API.loadPrivateData();
      } else {
         API.loadPublicData();
      }
   }
}

const component = Page(MyPage)

// what would make sense here is to have a method something like
// const component = Page(MyPage, () => MyPage.loadData())
// but then the MyPage.loadData logic would need to be defined
// elsewhere
```

This pattern will happen often: I'll want to load some data, then reload when the session changes. I'd like to understand the "react" way of accomplishing the same.

EDIT: I am not trying to pass a username or "loggedIn" flag through the HOC. That is to say something like `<WrappedComponent isLoggedIn={session.isAuthenticated()} {...props} />` won't cut it here. Tying the API logic to `props` requires that I check for changes in `MyPage.componentWillUpdate()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React: How to wrap component with HOC? (access login property across components)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42372614/react-how-to-wrap-component-with-hoc-access-login-property-across-components)

Comment: @NathanP. this is a similar question but I think there are a couple important differences. 1) I'm not using redux, this is just raw react. 2) I'm not trying to pass a logged-in flag or username through for rendering, I'm trying to perform some component-specific action whenever the session status changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a HOC you shouldn't place the `loadData` function on the wrapped component. Instead pass the function as a parameter to the HOC constructor.

Something like this might work for you. The `sessionHoc` function takes a callback function which'll be called every time the session state changes. Its result will be passed to `WrappedComponent` as a `data` prop.

```js
function sessionHoc(onSessionChange) {
    return function (WrappedComponent) {
        return class extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);

                this.state = {
                    data: null,
                };

                session.on('start', this.handleSessionChange.bind(this));
            }

            handleSessionChange() {
                this.setState({
                    data: onSessionChange(),
                });
            }

            render() {
                return <WrappedComponent data={data} {...this.props} />
            }
        };
    };
}

class MyPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        // Just access this.props.data here!
    }
}

const EnhancedPage = sessionHoc(function () {
    if (session.isAuthenticated()) {
        return API.loadPrivateData();
    } else {
        return API.loadPublicData();
    }
})(MyPage);
```

Hopefully this helped! :)